# Show child checkboxes on click of parent checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

i have a group of audiences with checkboxes hidden under its audience group. now, i want to show these hidden checkboxes onclick of the audience group name.

you can see more of the code im using here: http://jsfiddle.net/CnmEA/

i have these sample html code:

```
<div class='audience-group'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-group-checkbox' value='9' />
    <div class='audience-group-name'>
        JGG Enterprises
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='7' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Mucho, George
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='9' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Bo, Jen
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='10' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Gin, Junto
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='12' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Molina, Greg
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='36' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Berkely, Dada
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience-group'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-group-checkbox' value='8' />
    <div class='audience-group-name'>
        GBA Inc.
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='1' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Kapate, Jones
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='2' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Bingo, Gringo
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='4' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Doe, John
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='8' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Merio, Horhe
    </div>
</div>
<div class='audience'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='35' />
    <div class='audience-name'>
        Dalisay, JM
    </div>
</div>
```

im using the following jQuery code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$( '.audience-group-name' ).each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){

        $(this).find('.audience').show();
    });
});
```

});

i'm kinda new to jQuery, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CnmEA/5/

And the modified JS:

```
$('.audience-group-name').click(function() {
       $(this).parent().nextUntil('.audience-group').show();
});
```

The main problem with your JS was `$(this).find('.audience').show()`. The jQuery `find()` method looks for descendants of jQuery object that is calling the method. In this case, that object is `$(this)`, which refers to an element with the class `.audience-group-name`. However, the elements you want to show are not descendants of that element. You need to go up one level (`.parent()`), and then select all the next elements until reaching the next element with the class `.audience-group`.

You'll also notice that I removed the `.each()` method from your code. When you bind the `click` event to `$('.audience-group-name')`, it will bind to any element with that class. When one of those elements is clicked, it will find the right elements to show because `$(this)` will provide the correct context. It provides the actual element that was clicked, and therefore the DOM traversal methods `.parent().nextUntil(...)` will find the correct elements.

Comment: i just changed .show() to .toggle(); and that's exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot for a great explanation @maxedison! i learned something new. :)

Comment: Nice. I did not know about the `nextUntil()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` function looks for the **children** of the elements in your selection. You should ne looking for the siblings of the parent [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/CnmEA/6/)

As a general design note: You have a classic HTML mistake when building a tree structure - emulating left offset with padding/margin. The proper way of doing it would be to place `.audience` **inside** the `.audience-group` [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/Vux2m/), then it becomes much more manageable.